# Why selected object is not display in console when it is clicked

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, jstree

I am using this demo: https://github.com/ezraroi/ngJsTree

API reference: https://www.jstree.com/api/#/

I made two examples

1. First I have a checkbox. When I select any checkbox, it show the selected item object (codepen: http://codepen.io/naveennsit/pen/MKJdOZ?editors=101)

   `$scope.getSelectedCategories = function() {
       alert('---')
       var selected_nodes = $scope.treeInstance.jstree(true).get_checked(true);
       console.log(selected_nodes);
   };`
2. But when I remove this checkbox the click and selected item is not displayed in the console (codepen: http://codepen.io/naveennsit/pen/RrKmxp)

I used same function in both examples, but the second one does not work.

Comment: You have multiple links to different external resources demonstrating your code.  Move the relevant bits into the post - people will be more likely to offer assistance if they don't have to open multiple browser windows just to figure out what code you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of jsTree .get_checked(true) returns "an array of all checked nodes". If you don't have a check box associated to a node then I'm not sure it will work. Or it will not work without a significant workaround. However, the documentation says that "if tie_selection is on in the settings this function will return the same as get_selected". This may give you the solution you seek. Otherwise you could change .get_checked to .get_selected
The documentation I used can be found [here.](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=get_checked([full])) 
It's pretty far down the page to find .get_checked fyi.

**EDIT**
I decided to just try it myself.

```
$scope.getSelectedCategories = function() {
    var selected_nodes = $scope.treeInstance.jstree(true).get_selected(true);
    alert(JSON.stringify(selected_nodes));
};
```

This alerted the object.